# What is the reason for overwriting super global $_FILES while uploading multiple files using code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file, file-upload, superglobals

Assume post request is validated, and functional code is good enough and just an observation mostly multiple file uploading Code Igniter Sample code looks like this,

Concern is **why Super global variable like $_FILES is overwritten ?** Is this a good practise ???

```
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
            $_FILES['file']['name']     = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['type']     = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['error']     = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['size']     = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];

            // File upload configuration
            $uploadPath = 'uploads/files/';
            $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

            // Load and initialize upload library
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            // Upload file to server
            if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
                // Uploaded file data
                $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                $uploadData[$i]['uploaded_on'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I guess that the CI's uploading class uses the `$_FILES` array directly (which, in my opinion, is bad practice). The form seem to be named `files`, while this is setting each file to the key `file`, which then will be used by CI's upload class. I wouldn't call this good practice though, it's just a hack to for using multiple uploads together with CI's upload class.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `do_upload()` function accepts only form name.

By default the upload routine expects the file to come from a form field called `files` in your case, and the form must be of type `multipart` (enctype="multipart/form-data").

This is the main reason we override `$_FILES` variable.

[File Uploading Class in CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)